# Любыми, даже самыми тупыми(,) вопросами

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая?

`Он может задаваться любыми, даже самыми тупыми(,) вопросами.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение факультативное, зависит от синтаксической роли слова, например: *Интересны любые, **даже самые тупые** вопросы.*

**[Розенталь, пункт 3](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120)**

Пунктуация зависит от синтаксической функции слова, посредством которого присоединяется разъясняющий оборот. Ср.:

*Дождь, **даже ливень** не помешал проведению соревнований* — здесь даже — усилительная частица; *Хозяин был приветлив, **даже весел,** с гостями —* здесь даже в функции присоединительного союза.

**Примеры**

*Ради этих пирожков мы готовы были на любые, **даже самые большие жертвы.*** Наринэ Абгарян. Всё о Манюне (2012).

Также  **[Нацкорпус](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CnMiLgosCioKJHByaV9jYXQ60YXRg9C00L7QttC10YHRgtCy0LXQvdC90LDRjxoCCAEqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCIAoeChwKA3JlcRIVChPQu9GO0LHRi9C1INC00LDQttC1MAA=)**